# Create dynamic stored procedure in mysql with table name only

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a dynamic stored procedure for table name only, I mean when I call the stored procedure with table name as parameter it should be display all details of given table name.

I am using this code:-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test1`(IN tab_name VARCHAR(40))
BEGIN
SET @t1 =CONCAT("SELECT * FROM '",tab_name,"' ");
PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1;
EXECUTE stmt3;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
END
```

It display error, and the error is:-

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Any one can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back-ticks surround table name.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test1`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `test1`(IN tab_name VARCHAR(40))
BEGIN
    SET @t1 =CONCAT("SELECT * FROM `",tab_name,"`"); -- back-ticks around tbl name
    PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1;
    EXECUTE stmt3;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

or (PHPMyAdmin or those not requiring delimiters):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test1`;
CREATE PROCEDURE `test1`(IN tab_name VARCHAR(40))
BEGIN
    SET @t1 =CONCAT("SELECT * FROM `",tab_name,"`"); -- back-ticks around tbl name
    PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1;
    EXECUTE stmt3;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
END
```

Hopefully you are going to do something different with this stored proc because it seems trivial and will be slower than just calling the `select`.

Comment: thanks Drew 
I am change some code which is given by you it's working properly.
thanks again for help

I am using 
CREATE PROCEDURE `test1`(IN `tab_name` VARCHAR(40)) NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER BEGIN SET @t1 =CONCAT("SELECT * FROM `",tab_name,"`"); PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1; EXECUTE stmt3; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3; END

Comment: Cool. Glad to hear it Kunwar.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean above. The back-tick gets misrepresented in the comment. One needs to do like an escape sequence to make it show up. But yeah, back-ticks.

Comment: FROM \`",tab_name,"\`");  ... so just a slash before the back-ticks (in comments, not in your real code! )